# Is there a way to convert Multibyte characters into single byte in teradata.

Tags: teradata

I have a file having records such as 'ＲＯＯＫＩＥＳ －卒業－' , but in table the data is present as 'ROOKIES -卒業-', though the values are same ,  but the lookup is not returning.

Comment: What kind of *multibyte characters*? UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.? Did you load using the correct client character set? Does your SQL client use the correct character set?

Comment: Hi Dieter, We got an external file having Japanese character in it. We needed to do a text match with that column provided in that file. Data in our tables are stored as Unicode. Though the values are same, we couldn't join.

Comment: Finally , upon investagating we found that the data was having full width characters. We used python to convert it into half width and then we could do the join. This added an extra step to process teh file in python and then load into Teradata. I was just wondering , if there is an UDF?inbuilt function in teradata like oracle : TO_SINGLE_BYTE to acheive that.

Comment: You should be able to utilize `translate`: `Translate('ＲＯＯＫＩＥＳ －卒業－' USING UNICODE_TO_UNICODE_Halfwidth)`